# Building a site that can export user input into a downloadable Shopify-CSV

Tags: python, shopify, export-to-csv

I want to build a site that could take user input for a product details and export them into a couple of different CSV Set-ups depending on the site they go up on. Each site has small differences in title set-up or Shopify specific set up. The core product specifics stay constant:

Item Name
Item Brand
MSRP
Cost
Color
Size

I would like for the user(me) to only have to enter the core product data info once and have it return 8 different csv set-ups.

I am good with HTML/CSS and beginner in JavaScript. I want to grow on languages that would help me accomplish the above. What would be the best language to use to accomplish this sort of thing?

Considering that I would learn Python...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference for this type of work. All interpreted scripting languages offer the same level of support for simple tasks like this. You can throw a dart at PHP, Python, Ruby, C# or Javascript and all will end up being about the same. It is just you that matters here. Use what makes you happy. This is not something where there is a clear winner. If you want the most examples and paint by numbers, you can't do better than Ruby.